# Conditional operator in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

do you know if Python supports some keyword or expression like in C++ to return values based on `if` condition, all in the same line (The C++ `if` expressed with the question mark `?`)

```
// C++
value = ( a > 10 ? b : c )
```

Comment: That C++ operator is called the "conditional operator" or the "ternary operator".

Answer (score 206, accepted):

```
value = b if a > 10 else c
```

For Python 2.4 and lower you would have to do something like the following, although the semantics isn't identical as the short circuiting effect is lost:

```
value = [c, b][a > 10]
```

There's also another hack using 'and ... or' but it's best to not use it as it has an undesirable behaviour in some situations that can lead to a hard to find bug. I won't even write the hack here as I think it's best not to use it, but you can read about it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Python) if you want.

Comment: I've always wondered what notation they rejected as "too confusing" in favour of this.

Comment: +1, You can use this kind of 'if' even with lambda expressions!

Comment: @Neil, not sure if you're referring to the syntax ultimately chosen, or who said "too confusing", but the PEP summarizes all the rejected alternatives among other info: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/

Comment: They should have used `test ? a : b`. The reasons cited for its rejection are weak.

Comment: +! for Not sharing with us the 'not recomended' way ;)

Answer (score 1):

simple is the best and works in every version.

```
if a>10: 
    value="b"
else: 
    value="c"
```

Comment: Sadly this block form `if a then b else c` and the functional immediate form `b if a else c` are brain bendingly inverted relative to each other (Python's inverted `if` is backwards from nearly every other programming language's immediate `if` ).